# How can I perform a 2D interpolation, without a grid in Python, using scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have the following text file:

82 83.2 92.5
89 90 100

These numbers represent experimental data having the shape **z=f(x,y)**, where **x** are the numbers from the leftmost column, **y** are the numbers from the middle column and **z** are the numbers from the rightmost column. The file has more experimental data points, but those two are enough for this example.

I am trying to interpolate the data above but I cannot seem to find an appropriate way. Most scipy interpolation methods give as example data that are on grids or meshgrids and `interp2d`, if I understood correctly, needs a little preprocessing before the data is fed to the function.

Is there any way to get my interpolation without such preprocessing? Ideally would be simply by reading the data into `loadtxt`, doing some slicing to separate the inputs and the outputs and then pass them to the interpolation function?

Comment: Are you looking for strategies like [Delaunay triangulation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27622663/8881141)? Loads of questions on SO about this topic.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!